# Analyze Power Bi in Excel - aggregated measures "cannot be placed in that area of the report" into Excel values

Tags: powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, excel-pivot

I have a PBi report published. Within the report I've created a summarizedcolumns table that the user can Excel analyze (instead of hiding all the protected data columns).

Per [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/desktop-troubleshooting-analyze-in-excel) I have ensured the columns to be used as values are set with aggregation:

[image: Sigma showing]

[image: and can also be seen in the ribbon]

And yet when analyze in Excel get the "field you are moving cannot be placed in that area of the report"
[image: Fun fun fun]

Sooooooooooo, what am I missing or what else do I need to do?

PBi desktop is Version: 2.118.828.0 64-bit (June 2023)